# How to show hidden message in IE6 also using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

This site http://www.webstandards.org/ shows "Skip to content" or 3rd tab but this tab doesn't show in IE6, I already use jquery so i need jquery solution to show this tab in IE 6 also same like it works in IE 7 and firefox.

I want to use same thing in my client site.

Comment: or this site: http://www.browsesad.com

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery equivalent would look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#skip').hover(
    function() { $(this).attr('background', '#fc3 url(/files/theme/a-01.gif) no-repeat center bottom'); },
    function() { $(this).attr('background', ''); }
  );
});
```

However, if the plain CSS solution doesn't work in IE 6, then there might be something wrong with the layout. Then it won't help to change the method of displaying the element.